# Matlab figure axis label puts subscript text in math mode

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm adding an axis label in my figure and I'm using the latex interpreter.
The label I want is $S_{\text{grown}}$. In other words, I want the subscript text to be non-italicised.

Unfortunately this throws the error "String scalar or character vector must have valid interpreter syntax:" which is apparently triggered by the \text command.

Is there a way to add a subscript with the latex interpreter turned on so that the subscript text is not italicised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\mathrm` instead of `\text`.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. I'm surprised this didn't appear in the documentation any where...